# Crashes when using boost::random

Tags: boost, random, crash

I got a relatively serious problem with boost::random.
Background: I'm using TDM-GCC x64 on Windows 7 x64. Compiler options are -g -Wall -fexceptions
I build Boost using the same compiler enviroment, but that shouldn't matter when using random since it is header-only(?)

So now my problem:
I got this function:

```
#define PRNG_GENERATOR boost::mt19937

COORD function_g(int depth)
    {
        double _range;
        _range = 1/(depth + 1.0f);

        boost::uniform_real<double> range(-_range, _range);

        boost::variate_generator<PRNG_GENERATOR&, boost::uniform_real<double> > v_png(*this->m_prng, range);

        return v_png();
    }
```

When I call this function my program crashes with an c0000026 Error in the ntdll.dll module.
The crash is always displayed by gdb on the first line of the ()-operator of the random number engine of boost (in this case it is in the file mersenne_twiseter.hpp at line 319 which is "if(i == n)" - not actually something I would expect to cause a crash).
And the even more strange thing is, that this crash just appeared - I didn't commited any code changes, just a (clean) recompile and every build after the first showing the crash just crashes....!?

I spend now about one hour searching the internet for this mysterious c0000026 error, but didn't found anything valueable....

Someone got a tip how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us how `this->m_prng` is initialized.  Are you sure it points to a valid
object of type `boost::mt19937`?  The rest of it looks OK, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah thanks for the pointer, here ist is: this->m_prng = new PRNG_GENERATOR(this->m_ec.map_randseed); However, this->m_prng is only used in the above function and the here shown piece of the class' constructor... currently I use srand + rand for testing, but they aren't satisfying in terms of uniform distribution and "randomness"

Comment: @csde: Are you absolutely sure that `PRNG_GENERATOR` is `#define`-ed identically in each translation unit?  A `typedef` at class scope would be more in the spirit of C++, and allows the compiler to do more type checking.

Comment: @csde: Another suggestion I'd make is to strip your code down to a bare minimum, self-contained, compilable example that reproduces the crash you're seeing.  There's a good chance that you'll find the problem yourself by going through that exercise.  If not, at least you'll have a small, self-contained example that you can post here.  It's hard to say what might be going wrong, without seeing all the code involved.

Comment: Well I now tracked the issue down to checked_delete.hpp. I resolved the issue trough moving all functions using Boost to an extra DLL. Well not very clean nor flexible, but it doesn't crash (for now)...